# Java, How to Instance HttpCookie from a String, any convenient ways?

Tags: java, string-parsing, httpcookie

I have got a cookie string from HTTP response header like the following line:

```
name=value; path=/; domain=.g.cn; expire=...
```

I can parse the above line to key-value pairs, and, also it's easy to set the name and value to HttpCookie instance as this pair comes the first.

But how to set the other pairs since I don't know which set-method corresponds to the name of the next name-value pair. Traverse all possible keys a cookie may contian and call the matched set-method, like below snippet?

```
if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("path"))
 cookie.setPath(value);
else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("domain"))
 cookie.setDomain(value);
```

That's foolish, any convenient ways?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HttpCookie provides a parse(...) method that does the work for you. Look at the [JavaDoc here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29). If this is not what you want then look at the source code of its method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `HashMap<String, String>` then just iterate through the cookie string adding new hash entries, then, once you're done, you can do something like `cookie.setPath(hash.get("path"))` and `cookie.setDomain(hash.get("domain"))`